# Implement multi-threading in perl while fetch file from remote server?

Tags: perl, perl-module

How to implement multi threading in my code to reduce time.

```
if(exists $ddts_attachments->{$id}->{'urls'}){
  sub do {
    foreach my $url(sort keys %{$ddts_attachments->{$id}->{'urls'}}){
      $ENV{HTTP_proxy}=$proxy_url;
      my $ff = File::Fetch->new(uri => $url);
      my $where = $ff->fetch(to => "/attachments5/$id/");
      my $file = $ff->file;
      delete $ENV{HTTP_proxy};
      print "url: $file attached to $id key \n ......\n";
    }
  }
}
```

here In hash `$ddts_attachments` I have stored list of urls, from these urls I have to fetch files and store under directory.
please anyone can help me how to implement multi threading that helps to reduce time.

Comment: now I'm running in windows. but in future it has to run in linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```
use strict;
use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

my $queue = Thread::Queue->new();
my @threads;
my $maxthread = 5;  #how many threads are you want
push @threads, threads->create(\&worker) for 1 .. $maxthread;

if(exists $ddts_attachments->{$id}->{'urls'}){
    foreach my $url(sort keys %{ $ddts_attachments->{$id}->{'urls'} }){
      $queue->enqueue($url);      
    }
    $queue->enqueue(undef) for 1 .. $maxthread;  #no more data to process
}
#wait here until all worker finish
$_->join for @threads;

sub worker  {
    while (defined(my $url = $queue->dequeue)) {
        my $tid = threads->tid;
        print "Thread $tid got $url\n";
        #download and store the url
        local $ENV{HTTP_proxy} = $proxy_url;
        my $ff = File::Fetch->new(uri => $url);
        my $where = $ff->fetch(to => "/attachments5/$id/");
        my $file = $ff->file;
        print "Thread $tid url: $file attached to $id key \n ......\n";     
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply amon, But how to get value of url in sub routine worker??

Comment: @user3177669 I didn't write the code, user1126070 did. The URL is passed to the worker via the `$queue`. What exactly is your question?